# Why do I get an error or Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'innerHTML' of null?

Tags: javascript, html

```js
function show() {
  var now = new Date();
  var year = now.getFullYear(),
    month = now.getMonth() + 1,
    date = now.getDate(),
    day = now.getDay(),
    hour = now.getHours(),
    minute = now.getMinutes(),
    second = now.getSeconds(),
    hour = check(hour);
  minute = check(minute);
  second = check(second);

  var week = ["Sunday", "Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday\n"];
  day = week[day];
  var t = "Today is:" + year + "year" + month + "month" + date + hour + ":" + minute + ":" + second;
  return t;
}

function check(i) {
  if (i < 0) {
    i = "o" + i;
  }
  return i;
}
var h = document.getElementById("show");
h.innerHTML = show();

var h = document.getElementById("show");
setInterval(function() {
  h.innerHTML = show();
}, 1000);
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Title</title>
  <script src="../js/date.js"></script>
</head>

<body>

  <div id="show"></div>


</body>

</html>
```

I hope to display the current system time on the web page using an external link method, but I don't know why an error occurs，Is it because of code error code? i think i need help，Please help me debug the code

Comment: You're code seems to work fine here.

Comment: Embedding js into html he works fine, but I hope this can be solved with external linking

Comment: Can you please a bit more context to better understand how you're importing the function, where are the files located etc.. ?

Comment: Do not hesitate to add an answer of how you solve your problem. This might help someone else ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You get that because you try to access your HTML element before the page has loaded. You can add the defer keyword at your html file in the script tag and it should be ok

```
<script src="../js/date.js" defer></script>
```